# How Should I save input values of HTML form in sql from php

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "candidatesList";
        //create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
//        $sql = "INSERT INTO candidatesListFields (Sourcing_HR, DOS, Candidate_Name, Total_Experience, Current_CTC, Expected_CTC, Current_Location, Preferred_Location) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '','','')";
    ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 header">
                <h3 class="pull-left">Track your Candidates</h3>
                <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-primary exportBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".exportTable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save saveIcon"></i>&nbsp;Export to Excel</button>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 formWrapper">
                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="sourcingHR">Sourcing HR</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sourcingHR" value="<?php echo $Sourcing_HR;?>" name="Sourcing_HR" placeholder="Sourcing HR">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="dateOfSourcing">Date of Sourcing</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateOfSourcing" name="DOS" placeholder="Date of sourcing">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="candidateName">Candidate Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="candidateName" name="Candidate_Name" placeholder="Candidate Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="totalExperience">Total Experience</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalExperience" name="Total_Experience" placeholder="Total Experience">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="currCTC">Curr. CTC</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currCTC" name="Current_CTC" placeholder="Current CTC">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="expCTC">Exp. CTC</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="expCTC" name="Expected_CTC" placeholder="Expected CTC">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="currLocation">Current Location</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currLocation" name="Current_Location" placeholder="Current Location">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="prefLocation">Preferred Location</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prefLocation" name="Preferred_Location" placeholder="Preferred Location">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 text-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk saveIcon"></i>&nbsp;Save
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here I have created Data base and now I want to save values into the database for the following fields but it is giving undefined index. what can I do for this.

```
        if(!empty($_POST['Sourcing_HR'] AND $_POST['DOS'] AND $_POST['Candidate_Name'] AND $_POST['Candidate_Name'] AND $_POST['Total_Experience'] AND $_POST['Current_CTC'] AND $_POST['Expected_CTC'] AND $_POST['Current_Location'] AND $_POST['Preferred_Location'])){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO candidatesListFields (Sourcing_HR, DOS, Candidate_Name, Total_Experience, Current_CTC, Expected_CTC, Current_Location, Preferred_Location) VALUES ('$Sourcing_HR', '$DOS', '$Candidate_Name', '$Total_Experience', '$Current_CTC', '$Expected_CTC','$Current_Location','$Preferred_Location')";
            echo($_POST[$Sourcing_HR.' '. $DOS.' '. $Candidate_Name.' '. $Total_Experience.' '. $Current_CTC.' '. $Expected_CTC.' '. $Current_Location.' '. $Preferred_Location]);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['Sourcing_HR'])) {
            $Sourcing_HR = $_POST['Sourcing_HR'];
        }

    ?>
```

This is not working properly please help if anyone out there*

```js
 <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "candidatesList";
        //create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
//        $sql = "INSERT INTO candidatesListFields (Sourcing_HR, DOS, Candidate_Name, Total_Experience, Current_CTC, Expected_CTC, Current_Location, Preferred_Location) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '','','')";
    ?>
    
    <?php
        $sql = "INSERT INTO candidatesListFields (Sourcing_HR, DOS, Candidate_Name, Total_Experience, Current_CTC, Expected_CTC, Current_Location, Preferred_Location) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '','','')";
        // getting values of input fields from form
        $Sourcing_HR = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Sourcing_HR']);
        $DOS = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['DOS']); 
        $Candidate_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Candidate_Name']); 
        $Total_Experience = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Total_Experience']);
        $Current_CTC = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Current_CTC']);
        $Expected_CTC = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Expected_CTC']);
        $Current_Location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Current_Location']);
        $Preferred_Location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Preferred_Location']);
    
        if(!empty($_POST['Sourcing_HR'] AND $_POST['DOS'] AND $_POST['Candidate_Name'] AND $_POST['Candidate_Name'] AND $_POST['Total_Experience'] AND $_POST['Current_CTC'] AND $_POST['Expected_CTC'] AND $_POST['Current_Location'] AND $_POST['Preferred_Location'])){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO candidatesListFields (Sourcing_HR, DOS, Candidate_Name, Total_Experience, Current_CTC, Expected_CTC, Current_Location, Preferred_Location) VALUES ('$Sourcing_HR', '$DOS', '$Candidate_Name', '$Total_Experience', '$Current_CTC', '$Expected_CTC','$Current_Location','$Preferred_Location')";
            echo($_POST[$Sourcing_HR.' '. $DOS.' '. $Candidate_Name.' '. $Total_Experience.' '. $Current_CTC.' '. $Expected_CTC.' '. $Current_Location.' '. $Preferred_Location]);
        }
    
        if (isset($_POST['Sourcing_HR'])) {
            $Sourcing_HR = $_POST['Sourcing_HR'];
        }
        
    ?>
```

```html
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 header">
                <h3 class="pull-left">Track your Candidates</h3>
                <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-primary exportBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".exportTable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save saveIcon"></i>&nbsp;Export to Excel</button>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 formWrapper">
                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="sourcingHR">Sourcing HR</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sourcingHR" value="<?php echo $Sourcing_HR;?>" name="Sourcing_HR" placeholder="Sourcing HR">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="dateOfSourcing">Date of Sourcing</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateOfSourcing" name="DOS" placeholder="Date of sourcing">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="candidateName">Candidate Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="candidateName" name="Candidate_Name" placeholder="Candidate Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="totalExperience">Total Experience</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalExperience" name="Total_Experience" placeholder="Total Experience">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="currCTC">Curr. CTC</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currCTC" name="Current_CTC" placeholder="Current CTC">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="expCTC">Exp. CTC</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="expCTC" name="Expected_CTC" placeholder="Expected CTC">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="currLocation">Current Location</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currLocation" name="Current_Location" placeholder="Current Location">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                            <label for="prefLocation">Preferred Location</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prefLocation" name="Preferred_Location" placeholder="Preferred Location">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 text-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk saveIcon"></i>&nbsp;Save
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*

Comment: Could you please provide error message you are getting

Comment: 1. Why are you repeating parts of the code several times? 2. You're trying to escape post-variables (using mysql_real_escape_string()) without checking of they exist (or even if the request is a post at all). That means that you're trying to access all those `$_POST`-variables on _every_ request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` does not accept multiple parameters, and even if it did (like `isset()`) it would expect them to be separated by commas (not `AND`).

You can check that all expected `POST` keys exist with `isset()` in a single call like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Sourcing_HR'], $_POST['DOS'], $_POST['Candidate_Name'],
          $_POST['Candidate_Name'], $_POST['Total_Experience'], $_POST['Current_CTC'],
          $_POST['Expected_CTC'], $_POST['Current_Location'], $_POST['Preferred_Location'])) {
```

Or if you wish, use `!empty()` to ensure that none of the values are empty and do not contain the string `0`.  `!empty()` must be called on each element though.

```
if (!empty($_POST['Sourcing_HR']) && !empty($_POST['DOS']) && !empty($_POST['Candidate_Name'])
    && !empty($_POST['Candidate_Name']) && !empty($_POST['Total_Experience'])
    && !empty($_POST['Current_CTC']) && !empty($_POST['Expected_CTC'])
    && !empty($_POST['Current_Location']) && !empty($_POST['Preferred_Location'])) {
```

If you wish to offer individualized feedback on specific fields that did not contain required data, you will have to make separate if conditions (more code to write).

After you have checked that all expected elements exist, please use prepared statement with placeholders and bound parameters for security and stability (rather than mysqli escaping).

Here is an untested suggestion using object-oriented syntax:

```
if (!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "candidatesList")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error: " , $conn->connect_error;  // don't show exact error publicly
} else {
    if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO candidatesListFields (Sourcing_HR, DOS, Candidate_Name, Total_Experience, Current_CTC, Expected_CTC, Current_Location, Preferred_Location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {
        echo "Prepare Syntax Error: " , $conn->error;   // don't show exact error publicly
    } else {
        if (!$stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $_POST['Sourcing_HR'], $_POST['DOS'], $_POST['Candidate_Name'], $_POST['Total_Experience'], $_POST['Current_CTC'], $_POST['Expected_CTC'], $_POST['Current_Location'], $_POST['Preferred_Location']) || !$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Query Error: " , $stmt->error;   // don't show exact error publicly
        }else{
            echo "Success";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U Should Used `&& !empty($_POST['DOS'])`not the `,`